# Reclassifying multiple rasters using ModelBuilder of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, modelbuilder, reclassify

[image]

I am using ArcMap 10.1 or 10.2.

I have a folder with more than 500 raster (DEM) and i want to reclassify (equal interval method) each of them but number of classes in each case is determined by the number of 100m elevation bands. i.e number of classes =(max elevation- minimum elevation)/100. I have obtained max and minimum elevation of each raster from GetRasterProerties tool.

How do I put this custom number of classes for each raster using ModelBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the model only [Calculate value tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/calculate-value.htm) to compute the number of bands using your equation then use the output as [inline variable substitution](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-using-inline-variable-substitution.htm) into the correct parameter of the slice tool.

Comment: Thanks a  lot!! It worked.